# WPF C# MVVM Context menu displayed depend on Selected/unselected row but right mouse button selects the row

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, contextmenu

I am updating a simple app from Code Behind to MVVM. The app has a DataGrid. The ContextMenu displayed depends upon whether a row is selected or not. Unfortunatley when I click the RIGHT mouse button on an **unselected** row it selects the row and displays the 'Selected' context menu. If I then explicitly de-select the row and click the RIGHT mouse button the correct 'Unselected' context menu is displayed. How can I stop the Right mouse button selecting a row within the MVVM  context?

I have created a simple example to illustate the problem.
(I use Fody to handle property changes and the Microsoft MVVM Toolkit.)

XAML:```

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridToggleSelection.Views.DataGridToggleView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridToggleSelection.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="DataGridToggleView" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="PopupNoSelection">
            <MenuItem Name="NewItem" Header="No Item Selection" Command="{Binding NoSelectionClick}" />
        </ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="PopupSelection">
            <MenuItem Name="AmmendItem" Header="Item Selection" Command="{Binding SelectionClick}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Window.Resources>
    
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgToggle" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" SelectionMode="Single" 
                    SelectedItem="{Binding ToggleSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding ToggleRows}">

            <DataGrid.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedItems.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PopupNoSelection}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedItems.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PopupSelection}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Style>
            
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rubbish" Binding="{Binding Rubbish, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>

            <!-- Toggle Selected item & set Selected Item Colour -->
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="DoSelectedRow" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LimeGreen" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>

        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
Xaml.cs (Used only to de-select a row. Since its only visual it doesn't violate MVVM.)
```

```
public partial class DataGridToggleView : Window
{
    public DataGridToggleView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void DoSelectedRow(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;
        if (cell != null && !cell.IsEditing)
        {
            DataGridRow row = FindVisualParent<DataGridRow>(cell);
            if (row != null)
            {
                row.IsSelected = !row.IsSelected;
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public static Parent FindVisualParent<Parent>(DependencyObject child) where Parent : DependencyObject
    {
        DependencyObject parentObject = child;

        while (!((parentObject is System.Windows.Media.Visual)
                || (parentObject is System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Visual3D)))
        {
            if (parentObject is Parent || parentObject == null)
            {
                return parentObject as Parent;
            }
            else
            {
                parentObject = (parentObject as FrameworkContentElement).Parent;
            }
        }
        parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parentObject);
        if (parentObject is Parent || parentObject == null)
        {
            return parentObject as Parent;
        }
        else
        {
            return FindVisualParent<Parent>(parentObject);
        }
    }
}
```

```
ViewModel:
```

```
 public class DataGridToggleViewModel : ObservableObject
    {

        private DataGridToggleModel _toggleSelected;

        public DataGridToggleModel ToggleSelected
        {
            get { return _toggleSelected; }
            set 
            {
                _toggleSelected = value; 
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<DataGridToggleModel> ToggleRows { get; set; }
        public List<DataGridToggleModel> ToggleList { get; set; }

        public ICommand NoSelectionClick { get; set; }
        public ICommand SelectionClick { get; set; }

        static DispatcherTimer projTimer;
        int intervalWindows = 30;

        public DataGridToggleViewModel()
        {
            NoSelectionClick = new RelayCommand(NoSelectionCommand);
            SelectionClick = new RelayCommand(SelectionCommand);
        }

        private void NoSelectionCommand()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Selection Menu");
        }
        private void SelectionCommand()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Selected Menu");
        }
        public void PopulateDataGrid()
        {
            ToggleList = new List<DataGridToggleModel>();

            ToggleList.Add(new DataGridToggleModel { Rubbish = "Waste paper" });
            ToggleList.Add(new DataGridToggleModel { Rubbish = "Empty tins" });
            ToggleList.Add(new DataGridToggleModel { Rubbish = "Junk mail" });
            ToggleList.Add(new DataGridToggleModel { Rubbish = "Empty boxes" });
            ToggleList.Add(new DataGridToggleModel { Rubbish = "Newpapers & Magazines" });
            ToggleList.Add(new DataGridToggleModel { Rubbish = "Old clothes" });
            ToggleList.Add(new DataGridToggleModel { Rubbish = "Packaging" });

            ToggleRows = new ObservableCollection<DataGridToggleModel>(ToggleList);
        }

    }
```

````
App.xaml.cs:```

    using DataGridToggleSelection.ViewModels;
    using DataGridToggleSelection.Views;
    using System.Windows;
    
    namespace DataGridToggleSelection
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class App : Application
        {
            protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
            {
                base.OnStartup(e);
                DataGridToggleViewModel dataGridToggleViewModel = new DataGridToggleViewModel();
                DataGridToggleView dataGridToggleView = new DataGridToggleView();
                dataGridToggleView.DataContext = dataGridToggleViewModel;
                dataGridToggleViewModel.PopulateDataGrid();
                dataGridToggleView.Show();
            }
        }
    }
````

DataGridToggleModel.cs:

```
    public class DataGridToggleModel
    {
        public string Rubbish { get; set; }
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you set `row.IsSelected` if you don't want to select the row?

Comment: In the real App the Datagrid contains a list of events, birthdays, credit card payment times etc. If there is no row selected (with the left button) the the context menu displays options such as 'New event', 'Change database' etc. If the row is selected then the menu displays 'Amend event', 'Event repeat' etc. The only way I copuld find to toggle the selection was to use code behind. If you can recpmmend an alternative way then please let me know.